# Image is partially cropped sometimes when loaded in JetpackCompose LazyColumn item

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, image-loading, coil

[image]I am building an image loading library for Jetpack Compose. I know about Coil, and it does not meet my needs.

- I've build an AsyncMedia composable (Coil's AsyncImage was an inspiration here).
- When it is used in LazyColumn item and I am scrolling list fast and then stop it, sometimes, regularly, but not frequently, I am getting a cropped image (see screenshot).
- But file itself is fine, I've checked it.
- Moreover if I scroll this item out of screen and then back - it is perfectly fine. But this is not happening with Coil. Any ideas?

I've tried to follow Coil implementation as close as possible, including custom painter and so on, but nothing changes.

Comment: Sounds like you should just be using Coil.

Comment: >it does not meet my needs
what do you want to achieve exactly?